# Is there a $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that both $\sin z$ and $\cos z$ are zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

**Problem Statement**

> Is there a complex number $z = x + iy \in \mathbb{C}$ ($x, y \in \mathbb{R}$) that satisfies
>   $$\sin z = 0$$
>   and
>   $$\cos z = 0?$$

**My Try**

So I have
$$e^{iz} = \cos z + i\sin z = 0,$$
which contradicts
$$0 = |e^{iz}| = |\exp(iz)| = |\exp(-y + ix)| = \exp(-y)|\exp(ix)|= \exp(-y) > 0,$$
since $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Question**

> Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, @LordSharktheUnknown!

Comment: You could just note that for such a $z$ you would have $$1=e^0=e^{iz -iz}=e^{iz}e^{-iz}=0\cdot 0 = 0$$

Comment: Thank you for the added perspective, @MPW! =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

But $\sin^2z+\cos^2z=1$ for all $z$

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRozenberg!  This works too... +1 =)